# Passing variable in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have a ng-repeat loop and I want to pass a variable inside it...

```
<tr bindonce ng-repeat="row in elasticsearch.savedSearches | orderBy:['_id']">
    <td><a ng-click="changeServices('row._id')" bo-text="row._id"></a></td>
</tr>
```

but it only passes the string "row._id".

```
changeServices('{{row._id}}')
```

doest work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loose the '':

```
<a ng-click="changeServices(row._id)" bo-text="row._id"></a>
```

this should work:

hope it helps

You can also pick the row._id value in your controller without the need to passing it as above by doing:

```
 id = $scope.row._id
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<a ng-click="changeServices(row._id)" bo-text="row._id"></a>
```

ie, remove the quotes from the `'row._id'` else it would be treated as a string instead of variable.